# Create Auto-sizing TableView programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to create an auto-sizing tableview programmatically, but the cells are not increasing their height to fit the contents and consequently the next cell starts within the previous cell. What else do I need to do please?

**MyTableViewControler.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            cell?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let contentView = (cell?.contentView)!

            // Title
            let titleL = UILabel(frame: .zero)
            contentView.addSubview(titleL)

            titleL.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            titleL.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            titleL.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            titleL.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }

        return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add bottom constraint also

```
    titleL.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: I would have expected that table cell, as well as the titileL, to set their own intrinsic height

Comment: The label will set its own intrinsic height. And for automatic cell height, you should add constraints to its subviews in all four sides.